# Regext to encode angle brackets, but to ignore brackets used in xml tags

Tags: c#, xml, regex

How would I create a regular expression that encodes all left angle brackets `<` to `&lt;` using a regular expression. The regular expression would need to ignore all `<` and `>` symbols used in xml tags.

EG:

```
<test> test < test </test>
```

should be converted to

```
<test> test &lt; test </test>
```

So im basically trying to avoid encoding all `<` that have a closing right angle bracket.

NB: I have noticed that the `XMLDocument.LoadXml(string)` method already encodes all > that are not part of a left and right angle bracket pair used in an xml tag. So im not concerned about encoding these angle brackets

Comment: So you receive that malformed xml as a string input and cant change it at all?

Comment: @AlexK. My thoughts exactly. We seem to be having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323) here - instead of fixing invalid input, it would make much more sense to prevent invalid input from occurring.

Comment: I would want to avoid cases like this: XMLDocument.LoadXml(@"<item x=""test text"" y=""test < text""/>");

Answer (score 0):

Any regex solution is likely to be unreliable since malformed input might be irregular by definition. A quick and dirty regex that matches a `<` only if the nearest angle bracket is not a closing bracket is

```
<(?![^<>]*>)
```

but I can imagine a variety of situations (comments, CDATA sections, strings in attribute values) where this trivial logic might fail.

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pP4aK0/2).